# 5V proximity sensor to Rpi zero W GPIO

Tags: pi-zero-w, electronics, voltage

I want to use an NPN inductive proximity sensor with Raspberry pi zero w. The link to the sensor I am using is this:
https://robu.in/product/orange-15mm-npn-inductive-proximity-sensor-rm30-dc636v-unshielded/

I am powering it with **5V** but I cannot connect the GPIO of the pi with 5V directly as it may damage the board, So I need help to know various ways to reduce the 5V output of the sensor to 3.3V

**Till now what I've got is:**

- I've used a 1k and 360ohms resistor in series but that brings the value down to 0.40-0.30 V don't know why.
- I've tried using [this](https://robu.in/product/1-channel-isolated-5v-relay-module-opto-coupler-for-arduino-pic-avr-dsp-arm/) relay but it is too slow. I need to capture the data 30-40 times or more per minute, the relay is not fit for that.

One more option that I have in mind is using [this](https://robu.in/product/level-converter-4-channel/) logic level shifter.

> Will the logic level shifter work and be fast enough in this use case?

**If you have any other suggestions, they are welcomed! I really need to get this project working, Thank You tons for any help!**

Comment: logic level shifter, voltage divider circuit (two properly sized resistors - there are online calculators that will do the calculations) should both be fast enough for your use case, but try them for yourself.

Comment: You need to show us a schematic of the output of this device. Use the [schematic tool](https://raspberrypi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2074/how-do-i-add-a-schematic-to-my-question), or a clear photo of the schematic.

Comment: The link to the device is one of the least informative I have ever seen. Who knows what it outputs? Attempting to use less than the specified minimum is unlikely to be successful.

Comment: @SteveRobillard Okay, I'll try to use Logic level shifter then, will update if it works.

Comment: @Milliways So sorry sir for the less informative data. I myself am having a hard time finding the datasheet for that specific module. I will update if I find one. Also, I know using less than the recommended supply is the wrong choice but can you suggest what can I do then if I use 12v(My main supply is 12V) to supply it and reduce the 12v to 3.3V to connect to the pi's GPIO?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fRVISM.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The value of R1 is X Ohms. The value of X depends on the input voltage you use, and may be calculated as follows:

##### R1 = ( Vin - 3.3 ) / 10 mA

For example:

> if Vin = 6V: R1 = ( 6 - 3.3 ) / .01A = 270 Ohms;
> *or if you want to use 5mA for the Zener current*:
> R1 = ( 6 - 3.3 ) / .005 A = 540 Ohms

Note that 10 mA (or 5mA) is **chosen** as the Zener current from the data sheet.

##### How it works:

> The `OUT` terminal of Prox Sensor is connected to the *load*
> With the addition of R1 & D1 as the *load*, the RPi GPIO pin sees the following:
> When an object is detected by the sensor, the RPi GPIO pin is GND/0V
> Otherwise, when no object is detected, the RPi GPIO pin is 3.3V

##### Explanation:

The proximity sensor has an **internal** NPN transistor that acts as its *interface* to the *outside world*. The *Collector* terminal of this transistor is connected to the OUT pin, its Emitter terminal is connected to GND, and the Base is connected internally to the sensor circuitry which *drives* the Base when an object is detected.

- **When no object is detected by the sensor:** The NPN transistor is turned OFF; i.e. no current flows into the Base terminal, no current flows into the Collector terminal, and OUT is pulled HIGH by R1. While in this state, current flows from Vin through R1 and D1 - a 3.3V [Zener diode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zener_diode), and OUT is 3.3V.
- **When an object is *detected* by the sensor:** The NPN transistor is turned ON; i.e. current flows into the Base terminal, and current flows into the Collector terminal through R1. The OUT pin is pulled LOW because the current through R1 now flows into the Collector instead of D1, and OUT is ~ 0V/GND.

##### NOTES:

- You hadn't provided a schematic of the Prox Sensor when I posted my answer, and I have ***assumed*** your sensor is wired in the fashion shown in the schematic above. *You should verify the voltages **before** connecting this interface to your RPi GPIO.*
- 3.3V Zener diodes are available from a number of retail outlets at reasonable prices - [for example](https://www.arrow.com/en/products/search?q=3.3V%20Zener&prodLine=Zener&promoGroupLevel=pl&filters=Nominal+Zener+Voltage:3.3;Maximum+Power+Dissipation:500;&sortBy=calculatedPrice&sortDirection=asc)

Comment: Thank you for your time and effort. The sensor is wired in just the way you showed. I'll try to apply your given solution if the level shifters don't work. Will update accordingly, thank you again!

Comment: @IOT-Guy: Level shifters are not a good solution here. I could explain why, but it seems you've already decided... and experience is the best teacher, so go for it.

Comment: nope didn't use it. The one I got is faulty it seems. So got to try the other way now. I am powering the Sensor with 6V now according to the recommended supply as said by @Milliways. Trying to make it work with a voltage divider made with resistors but it isn't working. It is a great mess here lol

Comment: @IOT-Guy: TWO THINGS: **1.** I've **revised** my answer after getting better information on the sensor interface. **2.** The problem with voltage dividers is that they only give the correct voltage over a very narrow range of Vin; the Zener gives a constant voltage over a wide range of Vin. Have you got a DVM or an oscilloscope to make some measurements?

Comment: Yes I have got a DVM for measurements. Your idea of zener diode seems the only way. There seems to be another issue though. I got 3V from the voltage divider but when I connected the signal output pin to Rpi zero's GPIO pin, I got no input for some reason. I tried different GPIO pins, The code is correct, pins are correct, yet no input is detected by the GPIO pins.

Comment: @IOT-Guy: This is likely a different problem. I'd suggest you test the schematic here first, and verify its operation is as I've described. If it is, create a new question: explain what GPIO pin you are using, and post the code you're using to read the GPIO. If you have other thoughts, please advise.

Comment: Yeah that makes sense. First, I need to solve this GPIO issue because if this is not solved, the Zener diode circuit won't be of any use. I will update accordingly. Thank you so much for all your time and help mate! Hopefully I'll complete this project somehow

Comment: @IOT-Guy: I'll be disappointed if you don't  :)  And BTW, if you don't have a Zener, the voltage divider will work - just replace D1 with a resistor R2. Your DMM should show you the voltage changing as you bring an object into the sensor's field of view, and then withdraw it. If you use the voltage divider, just remember that its output voltage will vary directly in proportion to Vin, and that GPIO pins are quite *fragile*.

Comment: understood. The Vin won't change, it will be fixed so that's not an issue hopefully. Thank you for the advice

Comment: bro that GPIO issue is resolved! It seems the pins were not receiving enough current. I changed the power device of the proximity sensor and just like that it works. What a relief, was stuck at this part for a couple of days! xD

Comment: quick question. If I use a 3.3v Zener diode, then what is the maximum voltage that Zener diode can handle as an input without getting damaged?

Comment: @IOT-Guy: The quick answer is it can handle any voltage ***as long as you keep the current in the 5-15 mA range***. Use the equation I posted above to calculate the resistor value needed to limit the current. The long answer is in the Wikipedia article I linked above.

Comment: Alright, got it, thank you so much!

Comment: Hey, So I've got this BZX55C3V3 diode and the link to its datasheet is this (https://robu.in/wp-content/uploads/2019/12/BZX55C3V3-12W-Zener-Diode-Pack-of-40.pdf). The current is mentioned as 5.0mA and applying that to your given formula, the answer is 174 and so I need a resistor around that value so that it can safely bring the voltage down to 3.3V right?

Comment: @IOT-Guy: No - the formula is simply **Ohm's law** written to provide a convenient way to calculate the resistance from the supply voltage (6V - 36V according to your specs - right???). Plug this value into the equation for Vin. If you want to use 5mA instead of 10mA, use that value in the equation instead of 10mA.

Comment: @IOT-Guy: No - the formula is simply **Ohm's law** written to provide a convenient way to calculate the resistance from the supply voltage (6V - 36V according to your specs - right???). Plug this value into the equation for Vin. If you want to use 5mA instead of 10mA, use that value in the equation instead of 10mA. Pls see revised answer.

Comment: yes yes I understood your point. The 174 that I got was from this (12-3.3)/0.05 = 174. Now that the Zener diode can bring the voltage down easily I am thinking to change the Vin to 12V. Initially, as you correctly said I decided on 6V but now that I have a way to handle the voltage, so thinking to use 12V instead. I hope it is clear now.

Comment: @IOT-Guy: Yes, 12V will work fine - just double the resistance value. If I seem pedantic, it's only because I'm trying to make sure you understand. Many here don't understand even basic electricity - you'd be amazed at some of the ideas!

Comment: I understand your concern. I've come across such people. Will apply all of your advice soon. Thanks mate!

Comment: It works perfectly fine. As you said, I doubled the value of the resistor and used it. The current is around 0.3ma which is enough and the V is 3.2V just great! I'll be using Zener diode a lot more It seems ;) You are a blessing dude. Thank you so much!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/132797/discussion-between-seamus-and-iot-guy).